# The OR clause in a join condition takes more time to execute in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql

The below query in SQL Server takes more time [approx 600ms] to execute. Based on the query execution plan. I figured out that the code indicated is the culprit. How can I try to optimize this query?

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT ur.UserId, o.CompanyId 
--*
FROM [eapp].[UserRole] ur
INNER JOIN [eapp].[Users] u ON u.UserId = ur.UserId AND u.AccountId = ur.AccountId
LEFT OUTER JOIN eapp.UserCompany uo ON uo.UserCompanyId = ur.UserCompanyId AND uo.AccountId = ur.AccountId
LEFT OUTER JOIN eapp.ProjectUser pu ON pu.ProjectUserId = ur.ProjectUserId AND pu.AccountId = ur.AccountId
LEFT OUTER JOIN eapp.Project p ON p.ProjectId = pu.ProjectId AND p.AccountId = ur.AccountId
INNER JOIN (SELECT CompanyId, ParentId, AccountId FROM [eapp].[GetCompanyTree](1)) o 
  ON (/* the problem code is here */
      o.CompanyId = uo.CompanyId 
      OR p.CompanyId = 1
     )
WHERE ur.IsActive = 1 and ur.AccountId = 1 AND u.IsActive = 1
```

The Query execution plans are downloadable from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2iuy8DNKBfLOFlXQl95dVhEYk0/view?usp=sharing%20https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2iuy8DNKBfLbXFRRUtHXzNwbzQ/view?usp=sharing)
I though that there can be a `union all` that has the 3 statements that select the users in the organizations and the users in the projects and the users that are not allocated to any project nor belong to any organization. But that seems to be a bit clumsy approach to me. Can any one help me optimize this query to bring down the execution time?

I have tried the following. It's  **NOT** a good way to approach this problem. Maybe experts here can help me fix this issue with the best practices.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ur.UserId, o.CompanyId FROM [eapp].[Users] u
INNER JOIN [eapp].[UserRole] ur ON u.UserId = ur.UserId AND u.AccountId = ur.AccountId
INNER JOIN eapp.UserCompany uo ON uo.UserCompanyId = ur.UserCompanyId AND uo.AccountId = ur.AccountId
INNER JOIN (SELECT CompanyId, ParentId, AccountId FROM [eapp].[GetCompanyTree](1)) o ON (o.CompanyId = uo.CompanyId 
)
WHERE ur.IsActive = 1 and ur.AccountId = 1 AND u.IsActive = 1

UNION ALL

SELECT DISTINCT ur.UserId, P.CompanyId FROM [eapp].[Users] u
INNER JOIN [eapp].[UserRole] ur ON u.UserId = ur.UserId AND u.AccountId = ur.AccountId
INNER JOIN eapp.ProjectUser pu ON pu.ProjectUserId = ur.ProjectUserId AND pu.AccountId = ur.AccountId
INNER JOIN eapp.Project p ON p.ProjectId = pu.ProjectId AND p.AccountId = ur.AccountId
WHERE ur.IsActive = 1 and ur.AccountId = 1 AND u.IsActive = 1 

UNION ALL

SELECT u.UserId,null FROM eapp.Users as u
INNER JOIN eapp.UserRole as ur on u.UserId = ur.UserId and ur.AccountId= u.AccountId 
where u.IsActive=1 and ur.IsActive = 1 and u.AccountId=1 and ur.AccountId=1 and U.UserId 
not in ( 
    select distinct UserId from eapp.ProjectUser where isactive=1
    union all
    select distinct UserId from eapp.UserCompany where isactive=1
)
```

Comment: First - are you sure that the query as written is returning what you want? For all records where meeting the criteria for the joins except for the `o` join, every row where `p.CompanyID` = 1 will be matched with *every record returned from the base query in `o`*. That may be the intent, but it certainly seems possible that it is not. And, if it is the intent, then the time difference may be due to an notable difference in the number of rows returned by the query

Comment: Why do you think the union all isn't a good approach? Did it perform slower? Can you post the execution plans at PasteThePlan.com? My guess is that the OR query is doing table scans rather than index seeks. It's kinda like me saying, "Find me everyone in the phone book whose first name is Brent OR last name is Ozar OR middle name is Gregory." At some point, SQL Server says, "Screw it, I don't know how many rows will match - I'll just scan the table rather than use 3 different index seeks.

Comment: @RDFozz, yes, the logic behind this is that the user may belong to an company or a direct project and also it is that the users may be just added and not yet assigned to any company or project. The OR clause causes the table scan to happen and thus the delay [450 - 600ms] else the query takes approx 15-30 ms. I will post the execution plans for your reference.

Comment: @BrentOzar I have edited the question to provide link for the query exeuction plan uploads, please review the same and suggest

Comment: @RDFozz  I have edited the question to provide link for the query exeuction plan
 uploads, please review the same and suggest

Comment: Any updates on the plans, can anyone suggest regarding the alternative to using the approach given above.